# Apache shiro, return status 401 instead of redirect to url

Tags: spring-mvc, shiro

We're using Apache Shiro in a Spring MVC REST-ish app; for our API, it makes more sense to return HTTP status 401 (or 419) rather than redirect to another URL; I've been looking at the documentation, but can't see how to do so.

Does anybody know how to do so ? Is there a property to configure within the ShiroFilterFactoryBean ?

Comment: I found out I can redirect to a page, and make that page return a 401 status :). Would still like to see if there's a better way

Answer (score 3):

The redirect method is sometimes blocked by the CORS policy. My solution is to customize an AuthenticatingFilter, for example:

```
public class MyAuthenticationFilter extends FormAuthenticationFilter {
    @Override
    protected boolean onAccessDenied(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
            WebUtils.toHttp(response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return false;
    }
}
```

You can look at this [AuthorizationFilter.java](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/trunk/web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authz/AuthorizationFilter.java#L106)